# Realm for Android – RealmResult.sort() doing string based sorting?

Tags: android, realm

In my application I am querying some data from realm about below model class.
After then I am sorting resulting data using `realmResults.sort("point")`.
but result is not as expected.

Model class

```
public class FreeItem extends RealmObject {

private int itemId;
private int point;
private int freeQty;
private int freeItemId;

// geters setters
}
```

Querying code

```
    if(realm==null||realm.isClosed()){
        realm = Realm.getInstance(config);
    }
    PromotionPlan plan = realm.where(PromotionPlan.class).equalTo("id", planId).findFirst();
    if(plan!=null) {
        RealmResults<QtyDiscount> realmResults =  plan.getDiscounts().where().equalTo("itemId", productId).findAll();
        realmResults.sort("point");
        return realmResults.subList(0,realmResults.size());

    }
    return new ArrayList<>();
```

Before sort( debug values)

```
FreeItem = [{itemId:61},{point:12},{freeQty:1},{freeItemId:61}]
FreeItem = [{itemId:61},{point:120},{freeQty:16},{freeItemId:61}]
FreeItem = [{itemId:61},{point:24},{freeQty:3},{freeItemId:61}]
FreeItem = [{itemId:61},{point:60},{freeQty:8},{freeItemId:61}]
```

After sort it is same as before.

So i tried to write own sorting process using below code, but it generates an exception and saying, since they are realm objects cannot replace.

Any help?

Sorting code

```
        List<FreeItem> result = realmResults.subList(0, realmResults.size());
        Collections.sort(result, new Comparator<FreeItem>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(FreeItem lhs, FreeItem rhs) {
                if(lhs.getPoint()>rhs.getPoint())return 1;
                if(lhs.getPoint()<rhs.getPoint())return -1;
                return 0;
            }
        });
```

Exception

```
   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Replacing and element is not supported.                                                                                
at io.realm.RealmResults$RealmResultsListIterator.set(RealmResults.java:826)                                                                                        
at io.realm.RealmResults$RealmResultsListIterator.set(RealmResults.java:757)                                                                                        
at    java.util.AbstractList$SubAbstractList$SubAbstractListIterator.set(AbstractList.java:232)
                                                                                         at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:1888)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using `findAll()` method you can use [findAllSorted()](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmQuery.html#findAllSorted-java.lang.String-) and you can also give `ASCENDING` or `DESCENDING` order.

**From Realm documentation:**

> ***findAllSorted(java.lang.String[] fieldNames, Sort[] sortOrders)***
>
> Finds all objects that fulfill the query conditions and sorted by
>   specific field names.
>
> ***Parameters:***
>
> fieldNames - an array of field names to sort by.
>
> sortOrders - how to sort the field names.
>
> ***Returns:*** a RealmResults containing objects. If no objects match the condition, a list with zero objects is returned.

You have to use

```
plan.getDiscounts().where().equalTo("itemId", productId).findAllSorted("point",Sort.DESCENDING);
```

instead of

```
plan.getDiscounts().where().equalTo("itemId", productId).findAll();
realmResults.sort("point");
```

I hope it works for you.

Comment: Best answer on how to sort RealmResults.

Answer (score 0):

This is the Updated version.. you can try

```
RealmResults<Notification_History>notification_histories=realm.where(Notification_History.class).findAll().sort("notification_count");
```